# App requests in Facebook without re-logging and use session in Social Framework

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I've successfully connected in Facebook using Social Framework, also able to get list of my friends. However, I need to invite friend to use my app, I have been reading some articles and stackoverflow, that this need to use Facebook SDK.

Now, I able to achieve this using Facebook SDK. but then I need to re-logging (show pop up or direct to FB app). What I want is, to use session or `outhToken` that I have while I connected using `Social Framework` and use it in Facebook SDK. what I know, I have `outhToken` already. how to use this maybe to pass in `FBSession` or whatever class object to show app request ?

below is sample of app request.

[image]

Comment: can you please post the code by which you login to facebook.. thanks in advance

Comment: for facebook invitation you need to change setting from facebook app

Comment: @HemiB Have you got any solution for this I aslo stuck on same ?

Comment: @PavanMore still haven't able to do this. currently I use Facebook SDK to accomplish this, which user need to login again to invite other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumbled this question,

Facebook now remove graph API to grab friends that doesn't install the app. hence we cannot invite friends who doesn't install app.

even using Facebook SDK. if anyone has better solution or any updates on this, please share.